# set up alert on folder using csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csom, alert

My scenario, i can already set up alert on a list using the code below but i want to only set alert on specific document library inside the list.

```
                AlertCreationInformation myNewAlert = new AlertCreationInformation();

                myNewAlert.List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(CompanyName);
                myNewAlert.AlertFrequency = AlertFrequency.Immediate;
                myNewAlert.AlertTime = DateTime.Now;
                myNewAlert.AlertType = AlertType.List;
                myNewAlert.AlwaysNotify = true;
                myNewAlert.DeliveryChannels = AlertDeliveryChannel.Email;
                myNewAlert.EventType = AlertEventType.All;
                myNewAlert.Filter = "0";
                myNewAlert.Status = AlertStatus.On;
                myNewAlert.Title = "My new alert created at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                myNewAlert.User = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                var newAlertGuid = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.Alerts.Add(myNewAlert);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

updated code:

```
string targetDocSetUrlalert = CompanyType + "/" + CompanyName;
                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(CompanyType);
                Folder alertfolder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(targetDocSetUrlalert);
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.Load(list);
                clientContext.Load(alertfolder, x => x.UniqueId);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                AlertCreationInformation myNewAlert = new AlertCreationInformation();

                myNewAlert.Item = companylibrary.GetItemByUniqueId(alertfolder.UniqueId);

                myNewAlert.AlertFrequency = AlertFrequency.Immediate;
                myNewAlert.AlertTime = DateTime.Now;
                myNewAlert.AlertType = AlertType.Item;
                myNewAlert.AlwaysNotify = true;
                myNewAlert.DeliveryChannels = AlertDeliveryChannel.Email;
                myNewAlert.EventType = AlertEventType.All;
                myNewAlert.Filter = "0";
                myNewAlert.Status = AlertStatus.On;
                myNewAlert.Title = "My new alert created at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                myNewAlert.User = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                var newAlertGuid = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.Alerts.Add(myNewAlert);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

updated code using list itself and trying to filter event

```
 AlertCreationInformation myNewAlert = new AlertCreationInformation();

               // myNewAlert.Item = companylibrary.GetItemByUniqueId(alertfolder.UniqueId);
                myNewAlert.List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(CompanyType);
                myNewAlert.AlertFrequency = AlertFrequency.Immediate;
                myNewAlert.AlertTime = DateTime.Now;
                myNewAlert.AlertType = AlertType.List;
                myNewAlert.AlwaysNotify = true;
                myNewAlert.DeliveryChannels = AlertDeliveryChannel.Email;
                myNewAlert.EventType = AlertEventType.All;
                myNewAlert.Filter = "2";
                // 0 = Anything Changes
                // 1 = Someone else changes a document
                // 2 = Someone else changes a document created by me
                // 3 = Someone else changes a document modified by me

                myNewAlert.Status = AlertStatus.On;
                myNewAlert.Title = "My new alert created at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                myNewAlert.User = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                var newAlertGuid = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.Alerts.Add(myNewAlert);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `AlertType` from `AlertType.List` to `SPAlertType.Item`, then set the `listitem` to `newAlert.Item`

```
newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.Item;
newAlert.Item = list.GetItemById(1);
```

Comment: i updated the code but still am getting alert on the list and the folder..i want alert only on the folder

Comment: Okay, let me recheck it on my side and feedback you ASAP

Comment: ok i check multiple time,i get an alert only when creating a folder(the folder that the alert is attached to),if add a file in that folder no alert

Comment: if i change the name of the folder i get an alert,AGAIN if i add a document inside that folder no alert.

Comment: could you try to add alert for a folder via browser and check if you will get the same behavior or not! , I'm afraid, maybe it's normal where the alert raise on an item/list, in your case the folder is considered an item it doesn't care about its content!

Comment: via browser  it works as expected i get alert on adding files to folder too.,myNewAlert.Filter="2" should alert me only when a document created by me but i get aler for all changes

Comment: you get alert for all changes based on code or from the browser, I am confused!! what's the current status of your code now!

Comment: alert for all changes happens by code(even thought am filtering[myNewAlert.Filter="2"]),,the real way i want it to work happens by the browser way. NOTE FOR CODE am using alerttype.list

Comment: see i updated the code again